# Validating a collection of objects before deleting in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I am trying to only allow deletion if there are more than one users with the role "owner". I would like to display an error message that they cannot delete the user(with role owner) if it is the only owner. This is what the table looks like.

[image]

```
def destroy
  @user = @organization.users
  .active
  .find(params[:id])

  lastOwner = @organization.users
  .active
  .where(role: "owner")
  .where.not(id: @user.id)
  .count
  .zero?

  if lastOwner
    flash[:error] = "There must always be at least one owner, please give another user the role first"
    redirect_to teams_path
    return
  else
    if @user && @user.archive!

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to teams_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js   { render :layout => false }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That is my destroy method.

What is happening is that i try to redirect but i am receiving the error

```
Started DELETE "/teams" for ::1 at 2017-07-26 11:45:28 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/teams"):
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'


  Rendered /Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb (18.7ms)
```

once i receive the error the record does no t delete but the error message is not flashed but the page is redirected. When i refresh the page is when i see the error message. Any help please and thank you!

EDIT

this is the code for the delete

```
link_to('', team_path(user), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this member?"}, :remote => true, class: "btn btn-danger fa fa-trash delete_user")
```

these are my routes

```
teams GET    /teams(.:format)                                         teams#index
                                         POST   /teams(.:format)                                         teams#create
                                new_team GET    /teams/new(.:format)                                     teams#new
                               edit_team GET    /teams/:id/edit(.:format)                                teams#edit
                                    team PATCH  /teams/:id(.:format)                                     teams#update
                                         PUT    /teams/:id(.:format)                                     teams#update
                                         DELETE /teams/:id(.:format)                                     teams#destroy
```

Comment: Your link to delete is wrong. Can you edit your question and add the relevant view code? The screenshot is not informative.

Comment: Ruby also strongly encourages the use of lower-case only variable and method names, so `lastOwner` should be `last_owner`. This is because case has meaning in Ruby, constants are prefixed with capital letters.

Comment: How does your `config/routes.rb` look like? How do you generate the delete button?

Comment: @tadman i added the code, thank you.

Comment: @spickermann added my routes

Comment: Perhaps it is just me: Your routes look like you are trying to delete a team, but in your question, you write about deleting a user (or its membership). Can you please clarify?

Comment: team is just the name of the controller but it handles all the actions for a  user @spickermann

Comment: That link in the view code you provided should be correct, so are you sure that's the link you're actually exercising? It looks like the error results from `teams_path, method: delete` which is not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `redirect_to teams_path` to `redirect_to teams_url` in your `respond_to` code block.